# Selenium Webdriver: IEdriver getwindowhandles() method returns only 1 handle

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have recently started learning selenium. I am trying to automate a web portal. I have a button in webpage which opens another webpage. I am not able to switch to the newly opened window since `getwindowHandle()` is not returning the handle to newly opened window ( `getwindowHandle.size();)` returns **1** even the new window is open. I have given sufficient time for new page to load)

I googled this issue and one of the possible root causes I found was- protected mode not enabled in IE. Security settings in our company are controlled by group policy hence It's very hard for me to get this changed.
I wanted to check if there is any workaround for this issue.

Here is the code

```
WebDriver Driver= null;   
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","M:\\Drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe"); 
Driver= new InternetExplorerDriver(); 
JavascriptExecutor jes= (JavascriptExecutor) Driver; 
Driver.get("URL"); 
Thread.sleep(10000); 
Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='username']")).sendKeys("Username");    
Driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("Password");   
Driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Login']")).click(); 
Thread.sleep(5000); 
java.util.Set<String> handles= Driver.getWindowHandles(); 
// Check number of handles before clicking on the link.No. of handles   
//returned=1 
System.out.println(handles.size());    
Driver.findElement(By.linkText("Cases")).click(); 
//Clicking on TestLink will open a new webpage 
WebElement element = Driver.findElement(By.linkText("TestLink"));    
element.click(); 
Thread.sleep(5000); 
//Check number of handles after clicking on link.clicking on the link.No. of    
//handles returned=1. 
// Number of windows open at this point are 2 
handles= Driver.getWindowHandles();
System.out.println(handles.size());
```

### Driver.close();

> Following is the configuration
>
> OS: Windows 7 32 bit
>
> Selenium: v2.46 ( Putting correct selenium version)
>
> IEDriver- v2.46
>
> Internet Explorer: IE9

Comment: Do you know if it is not finding the parent window or child?

Comment: That protracted mode setting needs to be chacked **or** unchecked for all security levels there. I do not think checking them should be any security issue. Even so, company should not put restriction to testing machines. Talk to you admins

Comment: It's not with the protected mode settings..If that's the case the IE wont even launch

Comment: Can you post your code?post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: And use selenium 2.46 as you are using IEDriver 2.46

Comment: Hi all, I have provided the code sample in the post now. The control remains on the parent window. the selenium version I am using is 2.46